# Retrofit Body isn't showing desired response

Tags: android, http, retrofit

I'm trying to hit an API but not getting a response in JSON format. Here is my code:

```
 login.enqueue(object : Callback<ResponseBody> {
            override fun onFailure(call: Call<ResponseBody>, t: Throwable) {
//                serverLoader.value = false
                 Log.d("rr")
            }

            override fun onResponse(call: Call<ResponseBody>, response: Response<ResponseBody>) {
                Log.d("rr")

                response.body().let {
                    Log.d("rr "+it?.string())
                }
            }
        })
```

passing header Content-Type: application/json

[image]

Comment: did api service response/request with UTF-8

Answer (score 0):

Please check this out

```
it.convertJsonToString()
```